# document.location.href not working on Safari 2020

Tags: javascript, redirect, safari

I'm having issue redirecting a webpage on all browsers. I created a custom page for a client about a year back on `SHOPIFY` and now the redirect function no longer works.

I was originally using `document.location.href = "/cart"` and all worked well. But I recieved a call from him today saying the page wont redirect anymore on his `IPhone`.

I changed it to `window.top.location.href`, this fixed it for most browsers except safari. I understand that the best way for this to work on all browsers is the `document` version. But that seems to have been out dated this year.

```
    setTimeout(function(){ document.location.href = '/cart';},1000);
```

Checking the user agent of the browser and if it's safari we can do a different tailored version of a redirect, just haven't found out how to do this on the new safari yet.

@stanislav seems to have the same issue from this link, I suspect we will start to see the number of people with this issue growing.

[Why isnt window.location.href= not forwarding to page using Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223216/why-isnt-window-location-href-not-forwarding-to-page-using-safari)

Thanks to all for the input and suggestions, hoping to get the resolved soon.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Consider using [URL Redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection).

Comment: Sorry will update the post. It's a `shopify` website so I do not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: No. I've tried almost all the combinations possible of `window.location`,  `window.top.location`, `duciment.location`, all of the `assign()`, `replace()` combinations.

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one that has this issue now. Safari must of had an update recently. @stanislav is saying the same here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223216/why-isnt-window-location-href-not-forwarding-to-page-using-safari

Comment: I feel like Safari is the new IE - going rogue with the way it behaves, especially with unannounced behavior changes like this. I'm also aware that it stops running animations, even animated GIFs, at page unload.

Comment: Please add full path url  first then test

Answer (score 0):

try upgrade , Safari version 14 fixed this bug.