# Opening a new window on the same tab on Safari using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, safari

Right now, I am using a `window.open(link, "_self");` to open a page on the same tab. It is working on all the browsers instead of Safari. On safari it will open a new tab. Is there any way to force safari to open the link in a same tab.

Comment: Try this: `window.open = function(url){ window.location.href = url;};`

Comment: Is there a difference between `window.open(link, "_self");` and `location = link;`?

Comment: @traktor53 I also tried **location.href** and got the same result. Cannot open the page in a same tab on safari.

Comment: @sidverma Thanks, but it did not work. still it is opening a new tab on Safari but it is working on the other browsers

Comment: Do any of the answers to [Why isnt window.location.href= not forwarding to page using Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31223216/52171420)  work for you? It may also be interesting to re-test with popup blocking turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my Safari browser it worked. Try this:

```
var newwindow;
function openWindowInSameTab(url)
{    
   newwindow=window.open(url,'_self');  
   if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
```

Call function: `openWindowInSameTab('https://stackoverflow.com/');`